# what case the managedQuery method return null if uri is provided?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing some android application. I just wonder what will case the managedQuery method return a null value?

```
  if (getIntent().getData() == null) {
        getIntent().setData(Notepad.Notes.CONTENT_URI);
    }
    uri = getIntent().getData();
    c = managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, null, null, null);// return null value.
```

Answer (score 2):

`managedQuery()` will return `null` if any of the following are true:

- The `Uri` supplied in the first parameter is `null`
- The content provider implementation returned null as a result of the query
- If an exception occurred when the content provider attempted to process the query

I really do not like your call to `setData()`. Please try something like:

```
Uri uri=getIntent().getData();

if (uri==null) {
  uri=Notepad.Notes.CONTENT_URI;
}

c=managedQuery(uri, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

This way, you know your `Uri` will not be `null`, so if you get `null` back from the `managedQuery()` call, your problem lies in the content provider.

Comment: I like your coding style ... simple and easy to track....
I have checked ... First parameter is not null.
I am not sure if it is cased by the last two points..
Thanks.